# Non runtime allocation solution - ArrayList

Tags: java, android, allocation

I'm making a game in Java. I need some solution for my current runtime allocation, caused by my `ArrayList`. Every single minute or 30 seconds the garbage collector starts to runs because of I am calling for draw and updates-method through this collection.

**How should I be able to do a non runtime allocation solution?**

Thanks in advance and if needed, my code is posted below from my Manager class which contains the `ArrayList` of objects.:

Some code:

```
@Override
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
  final int size = objects.size();
  for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    Object object = objects.get(x);
    object.draw(gl);
  }
}

public void add(Object parent) {
  objects.add(parent);
}

     //Get collection, and later we call the draw function from these objects
public ArrayList<Object> getObjects() {
   return objects;
}

public int getNumberOfObjects() {
   return objects.size();
}
```

**More explanation:** The reason I mix with this is because (1) I see that the `ArrayList` implementation is slow and causing lags and (2) that I want to merge the objects/components together. When firing an update call from my Thread-class, it goes through my collection, send things down the tree/graph using the Manager's update function.

**When** looking at an Open Source project, Replica Island, I found that he used an alternative class FixedSizeArray that he wrotes on his own. Since I'm not that good at Java, I wanted to make things easier and now I'm looking for another solution. And at last, he explained WHY he made the special class:

> FixedSizeArray is an alternative to a standard Java collection like ArrayList.  It is designed to provide a contiguous array of fixed length which can be accessed, sorted, and searched without **requiring any runtime allocation**.  This implementation makes a distinction between the "capacity" of an array (the maximum number of objects it can contain) and the "count" of an array (the current number of objects inserted into the array).  Operations such as set() and remove() can only operate on objects that have been explicitly add()-ed to the array; that is, indexes larger than getCount() but smaller than getCapacity() can't be used on their own.

Comment: The garbage collector will run a lot. You have absolutely no control over when it runs. You need to account for that.

Comment: True, but since I've read about this topic, it is possible to make it nonfiring that often.

Comment: How many objects do you have?

Comment: @Petro: At the moment, three. But these will increase to about 20 - 30 during development.

Comment: Just curious, why are you querying 'mObjects' size, and using 'objects' afterwards.

Comment: @Petro: well, typing error. This is fixed now.

Comment: What is lifetime of your manager, do you reuse it, or do you recreate it constantly?

Comment: @Petro: My manager is created upon start, then I pass it to the renderer and the game thread as a reference.

Comment: Do you also call .remove on this array?

Comment: @Petro: Not for now, since I'm the beginning of the game.

Comment: How creation of 'objects' looks like?

Comment: That does not matter. I create them with different components like physics and all that stuff. But this is besides this issue.

Comment: Then only issue which I see is that copying of array could occur on resizing. If having ArrayList is not critical for you try to update code to use LinkedList and measure GC activity after that. I think you can safely to do this because you use indexing only in cycle, and this could be replaced by other 'for' syntax.

Comment: Seriously, someone wrote a class called FixedSizeArray? I would love to know what possible advantage that gave over a) using an array or b) using an ArrayList with an initial size the same as the FixedSizeArray. Both of those can also be accessed, sorted and searched without requiring any runtime allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I see that the ArrayList implementation is slow and causing lags ...

If you see that, you are misinterpreting the evidence and jumping to unjustifiable conclusions.  `ArrayList` is NOT slow, and it does NOT cause lags ... unless you use the class in a particularly suboptimal way.

The only times that an array list allocates memory are when you create the list, add more elements, copy the list, or call `iterator()`.

- When you create the array list, 2 java objects are created; one for the ArrayList and one for its backing array.  If you use the `initialCapacity` argument and give an appropriate value, you can arrange that subsequent updates will not allocate memory.
- When you add or insert an element, the array list *may* allocate one new object.  But this only happens when the backing array is too small to hold all of the elements, and when it does happen the new backing array is typically *twice the size* of the old one.  So inserting N elements will result in *at most* `log2(N)` allocations.  Besides, if you create the array list with an appropriate `initialCapacity`, you can guarantee that there are **zero** allocations on add or insert.
- When you copy a list to another list or array (using `toArray` or a copy constructor) you will get 1 or 2 allocations.
- The `iterator()` method creates a new object each time you call it.  But you can avoid this by iterating using an explicit index variable, `List.size()` and `List.get(int)`.  (Be aware that `for (E e : someList) { ... }` implicitly calls `List.iterator()`.)

(External operations like `Collections.sort` do entail extra allocations, but that is not the fault of the array list.  It will happen with any list type.)

In short, the only way you can get lots of allocations using an array list is if you create lots of array lists, or use them unintelligently.

The `FixedSizedArray` class you have found sounds like a waste of time.  It sounds like it is equivalent to creating an `ArrayList` with an initial capacity ... with the restriction that it will **break** if you get the initial capacity wrong.  Whoever wrote it probably doesn't understand Java collections very well.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. It was that I iterate through my ArrayList depending of how many object that was inside. So if I have three objects I called for the draw method 9 times, which was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what you are asking, but:

If you know at compile time what objects should be in the collection, make it an array not an ArrayList and set the contents in an initialisation block.

```
Object[] objects = new Object[]{obj1,obj2,obj3};
```

Comment: Hm, that's a good idea and I can implement it now. But for flexibilty it's not directly what I want, since things gonna go in and out through this collection during the game.

Comment: +1 Normally I would also suggest prefering ArrayLists but in Game Programming they can make a huge difference performancewise.

Comment: Well, that proved my suspicious about ArrayList's.

Comment: Whatever the problem here is, I don't think it has anything to do with using an `ArrayList` rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think you know what the GC is reclaiming?  Have you profiled your application?

Comment: Okey, to be more specific, Im making a game for android, and I checked with the DDMS tool, where I can see when GC runs.

Comment: What did the DDMS tool tell you?

Comment: This: `12-07 22:59:48.759: DEBUG/dalvikvm(579): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1246 objects / 59248 bytes in 66ms`

Comment: That doesn't mean the objects that were freed are the ones in your ArrayList.  Try this experiment.  Comment out all drawing, and re-run the DDMS tool to see what it says you GC'ed.

Comment: Well, true, but I suspects this is the case. However, it appeared first after I implemented this Manager thing.

Comment: What appeared?  Did your application slow down?  Did it run out of memory?  What does your draw method look like?  Are you allocating local variables there?

Comment: The GC collector started to run way often during the new implementation.

Comment: I'm assuming object.draw(..) is not the same method.  Can you paste that as well?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "non-runtime allocation"? I'm really not even sure what you mean by "allocation" in this context... allocation of memory? That's done at runtime, obviously. You clearly aren't referring to any kind of fixed pool of objects that are known at compile time either, since your code allows adding objects to your list several different ways (not that you'd be able to allocate anything for them at compile time even if you were).

Beyond that, nothing in the code you've posted is going to *cause* garbage collection by itself. Objects can only be garbage collected when nothing in the program has a strong reference to them, and your posted code only allows adding objects to the `ArrayList` (though they can be removed by calling `getObjects()` and removing from that, of course). As long as you aren't removing objects from the `objects` list, you aren't reassigning `objects` to point to a different list, and the object containing it isn't itself becoming eligible for garbage collection, none of the objects it contains will ever be available for garbage collection either.

So basically, there isn't any specific problem with the code you've posted and your question doesn't make sense as asked. Perhaps there are more details you can provide or there's a better explanation of what exactly your issue is and what you want. If so, please try to add that to your question.

**Edit:**

From the description of `FixedSizeArray` and the code I looked at in it, it seems largely equivalent to an `ArrayList` that is initialized with a specific array capacity (using the constructor that takes an `int initialCapcacity`) except that it will fail at runtime if something tries to add to it when its array is full, where `ArrayList` will expand itself to hold more and continue working just fine. To be honest, it seems like a pointless class, possibly written because the author didn't actually understand `ArrayList`.

Note also that its statement about "not requiring any runtime allocation" is a bit misleading... it does of course have to allocate an array when it is created, but it just refuses to allocate a new array if its initial array fills up. You can achieve the same thing using `ArrayList` by simply giving it an `initialCapacity` that is at least large enough to hold the maximum number of objects you will ever add to it. If you do so, and you do in fact ensure you never add more than that number of objects to it, it will never allocate a new array after it is created.

However, none of this relates in any way to your stated issue about garbage collection, and your code still doesn't show anything that would cause huge numbers of objects to be garbage collected. If there is any issue at all, it may relate to the code that is actually calling the `add` and `getObjects` methods and what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've added some more info in my edited question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do use a maximum number of objects for that specific ArrayList. Should I extend my question more and show how I grab this collection for making updates and drawing calls to see if it's optimized or if I'm able to optimize it?

Comment: @Julian: Possibly, though I really wonder if the issue has anything to do with this. Did you say you're only adding 3 objects to the list? I don't know how you'd end up with 1246 objects getting GCed if the issue were this list and those 3 objects.

Comment: True, but myself when looking at the screen experiencing more lag using this system, which I didn't see when I was used to call the update function of object itself in for example, the thread class.